# Tkinter how to start a thread only when the previous one finishes?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

So I have this piece of code:

```
xlist = []
        if fl != '':
            with open(fl, 'r') as fin:
                for line in fin:
                    xlist.append(line)
        for line in xlist:
            Thread(target=self.downloadSongList, args=(line,)).start()
```

My question is, How can I start only 1 thread at a time? Because right now, the program starts all the threads together, but I want each thread to start only when the previous one ends.
I tried to use .join() and queues, but nothing seems to work for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a bunch of threads. Just create one thread, and put your 'for line in xlist' loop inside it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? I can't quite understand what you mean, an example would me much appreciated.

Comment: I've done something like this:

`t = Thread(target=self.downloadSongList, args=(line,))
            for line in xlist:
                t.start()`

But I get an error "Threads can only be started once"